# What is the DNS resolve library in android-ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is there any resolver library in Android-NDK which does NAPTR, SVR and A or (AAAA) query?

Comment: `gethostbyname()` for A records?

Answer (score 0):

I think libcurl will meet your needs, make sure that you check it out. You can find instructions to use it in ndk here : http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/How_to_compile_libcurl and here: http://thesoftwarerogue.blogspot.in/2010/05/porting-of-libcurl-to-android-os-using.html